# url_to_postid returns 0

Tags: php, javascript, wp-enqueue-script

I'm trying to send the post id to js file to create a localStorage for each post by using their id's as  the key. The problem is when i try this code in php it returns 0, as a result all my pages have the same localStorage. What should i do?

```
public function button_js(){
    $url     = wp_get_referer();
    $post_id = url_to_postid( $url );

    wp_localize_script( 'likeButton', 'ajax_object',
        array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ), 'we_value' => $post_id) )
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts',[ $this ,'button_js']);
```

Comment: does `$url` contain the URL you expected ?

Comment: I checked now :http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/ So no :(. Why cant i get the right address?

Comment: what do you call "the right address" ?

Comment: the post's url.

Answer (score 1):

when you are at the post URL, you don't need to work with referer (which is not reliable moreover) but with `$GLOBALS["post"]` because you are in the PHP code which generate the page

then you can have the post ID with that :

```
$post_id = $GLOBALS["post"]->ID;
```

Comment: I solved the problem with get_the_ID(); however this may work too!